# Filter on rows based on date range. Error with date format

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, filter

I want to filter a dataframe based on a range of dates either side of the date of the maximum value in a series from the dataframe. Filtering works fine with manually entered dates e.g. '2018-01-05' but when that date is stored in a series object, it won't work - and i'm too thick to work out why.
I've tried string conversions and extracting the date from the series as a value but to no avail. Here is a stylised version:

```
    data = {'dates':['2018-01-01','2018-01-02','2018-01-03','2018-01-04','2018-01-05', \
    '2018-01-06'],'values':[-20,30,15,10,4,7]}
    data = pd.DataFrame(data)
    data.dates = pd.to_datetime(data.dates,dayfirst=True)

    maxval = data.nlargest(1,'values')
    maxdate = maxval.loc[:,'dates']

    start_remove = maxdate-timedelta(days=1)
    end_remove = maxdate+timedelta(days=1)

    data.loc[(data['dates']<start_remove) | (data['dates']>end_remove)]
```

gives ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

whereas:

```
    data.loc[(data['dates']<'2018-01-03) | (data['dates']>'2018-01-05)]
```

Works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Series.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmax.html) for index value of maximal `values`:

```
maxdate = data.set_index('dates')['values'].idxmax()
```

---

Problem is `maxdate` is one element `Series` instead scalar, possible solution is select by position with [`DataFrame.iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iat.html) and [`Index.get_loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_loc.html) for position of column `dates`:

```
maxdate = maxval.iat[0, maxval.column.get_loc('dates')]
```

Or select by labels with [`DataFrame.at`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.at.html) and get first value of indices:

```
maxdate = maxval.at[maxval.index[0], 'dates']

print (maxdate)
2018-01-02 00:00:00
```

Comment: Many thanks. that's frustratingly longwinded for what is a simple problem. Why I can't just access maxdate as maxval['dates'] or convert it as str(maxval['dates'] isn't clear.